# What effect do the various position values have on the body's children when their heights are at 100%?

Tags: css, html, css-position

Essentially can anyone explain this:

> Because body isn't positioned (or more accurately, it's
>   position:static by default), setting a child element to height:100%
>   causes it to be 100% of the height of the html element, not the body
>   element. Thus, if you want something to be as tall as the body is
>   (going down past the bottom of the page) use `body { position:relative }`

This statement is taken from: http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html It's is located at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Can you cite the text?

Comment: Here it is: http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html

Answer (score 1):

That statement is incorrect and **notice that the article is copyrighted 2004**. The body's height will be relative to the html element. Children of the body will be relative to the body despite it being set to `position:static`.

A simple example will prove that:

```
<!doctype html>

<style>
    html { height:100%; }
    body{}
    div {height:100%; background:#ccc;}
</style>

<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

Notice that the div element is still collapsed to the height of the body, which is zero. If you set the body's height to 100%, the div element and the body both expand to the height of the html element.

Answer (score 1):

This article is incorrect. Giving the `body` a position tag is unnecessary to achieve this. The body tag does not need to have `position: relative;` in order to have an element take on its height.

To make children of the `body` tag have a height based on percentage of the `body` tag, you should give the `body` a height. For the body tag to have a height that is 100%, you must also give the `html` tag a height of 100%.

For example: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mt72erzd/1/)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Now, the direct children of the body can give a height that is in relation to the body because the body's height is defined.

This line is simply wrong:

> setting a child element to height:100% causes it to be 100% of the
>   height of the html element, not the body element

For example, if you remove the height attribute of the `body` tag, the child tags will not take 100% height of the `html` tag: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mt72erzd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

What this basically means is that because content can expand the height to any given value which is different for most sites, the height is not constrained by the screen size like width would be, it can grow and shrink as needed. Therefore it has dynamic qualities and with grow according to the content inside it. However, we can change this behavior by forcing the base HTML element and each layer on top that to be 100% for example and then it would fit according to screen size and no larger.

In practice an example of this would be:
HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>Hello World<div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {height:100%;}
body {height:100%;}
div {height:100%;}
```

This would produce a div layer that expanded to the bottom of the page as opposed to only reaching as far as a line break after "Hello World".